# Alternatives to the "work stealing queue" model?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, concurrency, c++14

I would like to implement a task based model to process and digest the workload of my application, I think that now that we have C++11/14 it's time to try to implement something like that on my own .

With "task based model" I mean something that doesn't creates an excessive number of threads such that the cache coherency protocol is at stake and it's relatively cheap and simple to implement .

Of course with C++11/14 I have atomic ops and CAS too, so I have pretty much all the modern building blocks for concurrent programming.

I'm not sure If I have to outline this or not, if this can possibly change your answer, but in C++11/14 I found some difficulties in managing functions objects as first class objects when it comes to "pipelining" them, like executing a chain of functions of functions, In particular you can reach up to polymorphic lambdas but the fundamental problem about the returned types of the function objects still remains, and you can't chain 2 functions together if you can't "attach" the returned type of one function to the interface of the next function . I think that this is a limitation of the language AFAIK, something like the monads are not a thing that is 100% doable in C++, even with the latest C++14 standard .

Anyhow, please suggest an alternative to the *work stealing queue* model .

Comment: Although we have polymorphic lambdas in C++14, they're still meant to be statically polymorphic. This still shouldn't prevent them from being chained, just as long as the pipeline is known at compile time.

Comment: @E_net4 yes, that is a limit, at least in my case and in my view.

Comment: An article that you might find useful: http://www.1024cores.net/home/scalable-architecture/task-scheduling-strategies

Comment: It's disappointing how little attention this question received. @user2485710, did you manage to find any alternatives on your own and could maybe write an answer?